# Where does gtwcontrol -a on run from?

Tags: teradata

I want to switch on the `gtwcontrol`. I read [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Utilities/B035_1102_111A/Gtwcontrol.35.2.html)  that *it runs from the Database Window or comparable interface to the Teradata Database console subsystem, such as `cnsterm`*.

But since I am a noob, I dont know what I should do, and where I should specify this `gtwcontrol -a on`. I tried it in control line ..

(I am using Windows 7)

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Teradata Express running on Linux?

On the page you mentioned there's a link "Starting the Utilities".
Simply run `tdatcmd` on the commend line followed by `gtwcontrol -a`

Comment: +1 This is Windows 7. I tried command line, it did not execute

Comment: Your link was to Teradata 14 which is not available on Windows, is this an older version? Start the Teradata Command Prompt from Windows by clicking: Start>Programs>Teradata Database>Teradata Command Prompt

Comment: I found `tdxodbc` window similar to cmd. The connection is successful. It is waiting for SQL commands : `Enter SQL String`. How should I proceed? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what `tdxodbc` is, seems to be a test program for ODBC connections. It's definitely not similar to `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

login to your TD node type "tdatcmd" and press enter, then type gtwcontrol